# How not to specify a specific file in the import path of Vite?

Tags: reactjs, import, vite

After switching from the webpack, I ran into the problem that now in UI library imports it is necessary to specify the index file at the end, otherwise Vite does not see the element:
From this

```
import SlInput from '@shoelace-style/shoelace/dist/react/input',
```

to this

```
import SlInput from '@shoelace-style/shoelace/dist/react/input/index'
```

And besides that, vs code no longer automatically adds imports from this library (But maybe that's another problem)

Is there a way to return the previous view of the import path? Can I add something specific to the Vite configs?